# How to get simple graphics drawn on canvas with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, graphics, drawing

I am writing a program that will show a graphical representation (not animation) of fireworks exploding. A lot of my program is dedicated to giving the user options in their launches (such as color, type of explosion, trajectory, etc.). I have spent a lot of time tweaking my GUI panel to get it the way I want and now that I've redirected my focus to drawing the explosions on my canvas I am not able to draw anything in my panel. I have done numerous java graphics programs before and have been able to easily solve this problem in the past. I have had no such luck with this program and have grown frustrated. Does anybody see what my problem could be?

(Another issue I've been having is with my JSliders, but that's much less of an important issue for me)

Thanks for all your help!

CODE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Fireworks extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ChangeListener, ItemListener {
    protected int speed, angle, launch = 1;
JFrame frame;
JPanel guistuff, display;
//Each button (except 'button') corresponds to a color for the fireworks. 
//e.g. rbutton = red, obutton = orange, etc.
JButton button, rbutton, obutton, ybutton, gbutton, cbutton, pbutton, ubutton;
JLabel speedlabel, anglelabel, launchlabel;
JSlider speedslider, angleslider;
JPanel displaycanvas;
String fireworkcolor, explosiontype;

private void FireworkLauncher() {
    frame = new JFrame("Fireworks!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel displaycanvas = new JPanel();
    displaycanvas.setSize(800, 600);
    displaycanvas.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    displaycanvas.setLocation(0, 0);
    displaycanvas.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    displaycanvas.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(displaycanvas);

    JPanel guistuff = new JPanel();
    guistuff.setSize(800, 200);
    guistuff.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    guistuff.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    guistuff.setLocation(0, 600);
    guistuff.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(guistuff);

    JSlider speedslider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 10);
    speedslider.addChangeListener(this);
    speedslider.setName("SpeedSlider");
    //speedslider.setValue(50);
    speedslider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    speedslider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    speedslider.setPaintTicks(true);
    speedslider.setMinimum(0);
    speedslider.setMaximum(100);
    speedslider.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    speedslider.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(speedslider);

    JLabel speedlabel = new JLabel("Speed: " + speed + "   ", JLabel.LEFT);     
    speedlabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    speedlabel.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(speedlabel);

    JSlider angleslider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 90, 10);
    angleslider.addChangeListener(this);
    angleslider.setName("AngleSlider");
    angleslider.setMinimum(0);
    angleslider.setMaximum(90);
    angleslider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    angleslider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    angleslider.setPaintTicks(true);
//  angleslider.setValue(50);
    angleslider.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    angleslider.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(angleslider);

    JLabel anglelabel = new JLabel("Angle: " + angle + "      ", JLabel.LEFT);      
    anglelabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    anglelabel.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(anglelabel);

    JButton button = new JButton("Launch!");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
    button.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setLocation(650, 650);
    button.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(button);

    //The following six JButtons make buttons for each color to select the color of the next launch of fireworks.
    JButton rbutton = new JButton("Red");
    rbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    rbutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    rbutton.addActionListener(this);
    rbutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    rbutton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    rbutton.setVisible(true);
    rbutton.setOpaque(true);
    rbutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(rbutton);

    JButton obutton = new JButton("Orange");
    obutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    obutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    obutton.addActionListener(this);
    obutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    obutton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    obutton.setVisible(true);
    obutton.setOpaque(true);
    obutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(obutton);

    JButton ybutton = new JButton("Yellow");
    ybutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    ybutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ybutton.addActionListener(this);
    ybutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    ybutton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    ybutton.setVisible(true);
    ybutton.setOpaque(true);
    ybutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(ybutton);

    JButton gbutton = new JButton("Green");
    gbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    gbutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gbutton.addActionListener(this);
    gbutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    gbutton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    gbutton.setVisible(true);
    gbutton.setOpaque(true);
    gbutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(gbutton);

    JButton cbutton = new JButton("Blue");
    cbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    cbutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cbutton.addActionListener(this);
    cbutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    cbutton.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    cbutton.setVisible(true);
    cbutton.setOpaque(true);
    cbutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(cbutton);

    JButton pbutton = new JButton("Pink");
    pbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    pbutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pbutton.addActionListener(this);
    pbutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    pbutton.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    pbutton.setVisible(true);
    pbutton.setOpaque(true);
    pbutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(pbutton);

    JButton ubutton = new JButton("Purple");
    ubutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    ubutton.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ubutton.addActionListener(this);
    ubutton.setLocation(25, 750);
    ubutton.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    ubutton.setVisible(true);
    ubutton.setOpaque(true);
    ubutton.setBorderPainted(false);
    guistuff.add(ubutton);

    //Sets up the interface for the user to select an explosion type.
    JLabel launchlabel = new JLabel("Type of Explosion: ", JLabel.LEFT);
    launchlabel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    launchlabel.setVisible(true);
    guistuff.add(launchlabel);

    JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Splash");
    //Lots of random lines will display from the explosion site out to the rest of the canvas.
    radio1.addItemListener(this);
    radio1.setSelected(false);
    guistuff.add(radio1);
    radio1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio1.setVisible(true);

    JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Bubbles");
    //Lots of circles will display at the explosion site
    radio2.addItemListener(this);
    guistuff.add(radio2);
    radio2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio2.setSelected(false);
    radio2.setVisible(true);

    JRadioButton radio3 = new JRadioButton("Sprinkles");
    //Lots of little x's will display at the explosion site
    radio3.addItemListener(this);
    guistuff.add(radio3);
    radio3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio3.setSelected(false);
    radio3.setVisible(true);

    JRadioButton radio4 = new JRadioButton("Giant");
    //Explosion will draw ALOT (5000) pixels randomly on the screen.
    radio4.addItemListener(this);
    guistuff.add(radio4);
    radio4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio4.setSelected(false);
    radio4.setVisible(true);

    JRadioButton radio5 = new JRadioButton("Tiny");
    //Explosion will draw a few (100) pixels randomly on the screen.
    radio5.addItemListener(this);
    guistuff.add(radio5);
    radio5.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio5.setSelected(false);
    radio5.setVisible(true);

    JRadioButton radio6 = new JRadioButton("Random");
    //Will generate a random number from 0-4 that corresponds to a certain explosion type. 
    radio6.addItemListener(this);
    guistuff.add(radio6);
    radio6.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    radio6.setSelected(true);
    radio6.setVisible(true);

    ButtonGroup radiogroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radiogroup.add(radio1);
    radiogroup.add(radio2);
    radiogroup.add(radio3);
    radiogroup.add(radio4);
    radiogroup.add(radio5);
    radiogroup.add(radio6);

    guistuff.validate();

    Display display = new Display();
}

class Display extends JPanel {


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // PAINTING OF THE FIREWORKS!
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawLine(50, 50, 100, 100);
        g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 400, 400);
        repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
    String sourcename = source.getName();
    System.out.println(sourcename);
    if (sourcename.equals("SpeedSlider")) {
        JLabel speedlabel = new JLabel("Speed: " + speed + "   ", JLabel.LEFT); 
        speed = source.getValue();
        String speedstring = Integer.toString(speed);
        System.out.println(speedstring);
        System.out.println(speedlabel.getText());
        speedlabel.setText("Speed: " + (speedstring));
        System.out.println("speed slider was moved");
        speedlabel.repaint();
    } else if (sourcename.equals("AngleSlider")) {
        angle = angleslider.getValue();
        System.out.println(angle);
        String anglestring = Integer.toString(angle);
        anglelabel.setText("Angle: " + (anglestring));
        System.out.println("angle slider was moved");
        anglelabel.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
    //Calculations for the explosion trajectories go here
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Launch!")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK LAUNCHED!");
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Red")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO RED");
        fireworkcolor = "r";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Orange")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO ORANGE");
        fireworkcolor = "o";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Yellow")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO YELLOW");
        fireworkcolor = "y";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Green")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO GREEN");
        fireworkcolor = "g";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Blue")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO BLUE");
        fireworkcolor = "b";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pink")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO PINK");
        fireworkcolor = "p";
    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Purple")){
        System.out.println("FIREWORK COLOR CHANGED TO PURPLE");
        fireworkcolor = "u";
    }
    System.out.println(fireworkcolor);
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String radiotag = ((AbstractButton) e.getItem()).getText();
    if (radiotag.equals("Splash")){
        System.out.println("Splash");
        explosiontype = "splash";
    } else if (radiotag.equals("Bubbles")){
        System.out.println("Bubbles");
        explosiontype = "bubbles";
    } else if (radiotag.equals("Sprinkles")){
        System.out.println("Sprinkles");
        explosiontype = "sprinkles";
    } else if (radiotag.equals("Giant")){
        System.out.println("Giant");
        explosiontype = "giant";
    } else if (radiotag.equals("Tiny")){
        System.out.println("Tiny");
        explosiontype = "tiny";
    } else if (radiotag.equals("Random")){
        System.out.println("Random");
        explosiontype = "random";
    } 
    System.out.println(explosiontype);

}

public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(int speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

public int getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public void setAngle(int angle) {
    this.angle = angle;
}

public int getLaunch() {
    return launch;
}

public void setLaunch(int launch) {
    this.launch = launch;
}

public String getFireworkcolor() {
    return fireworkcolor;
}

public void setFireworkcolor(String fireworkcolor) {
    this.fireworkcolor = fireworkcolor;
}

public String getExplosiontype() {
    return explosiontype;
}

public void setExplosiontype(String explosiontype) {
    this.explosiontype = explosiontype;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Fireworks().FireworkLauncher();
}

}
```

Comment: Try putting the `frame.setVisisble(true)` method at the end.

Comment: You're posting 400 lines of code, and little of it has anything to do with the problem at hand. Why are you giving volunteers extra unneeded work? Instead, please pare your code down to the smallest functioning bit of code that compiles and runs and that demonstrates your problem for us, a [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: Camickr's answer is (as usual) spot on. Also, learn about and use the layout managers. You're trying to set component location by absolute positioning, and that's not the way to do it. Instead nest container JPanels,  each using its own layout, and then add components to these JPanels.

Comment: You're also doing variable shadowing in a **big** way, and this can cause major problems down the line. In fact, most of your GUI component variables are being shadowed.

Answer (score 2):

> How to get simple graphics drawn on canvas with GUI

Well if you want to display simple Graphics, then why don't you create a simple program to find your problem? Then once you know the problem you apply the solution to your real program.

Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()`. The only `paintComponent()` method I see in your code is found in the `Display` class.

The only place I see you using the `Display` class is:

```
Display display = new Display();
```

I don't see you add the component to the frame anywhere.

But even if you do add it to the frame you still may not see it because you don't override the `getPreferredSize()` method.

Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for a simple example of custom painting.

> Another issue I've been having is with my JSliders, but that's much less of an important issue for me

Take my initial advice to create a simple program to play with a slider until you understand how it works. Then add the logic to your main program. This type of a program is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and is used to simplify the problem. Then if it still doesn't work you have simple code to post on the forum.